# how to get column from Excel Sheet,if Excel sheet name contain space character i.e."Person Details"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, excel-2010

here i m using ADO.Net for connect to Excel file using specified connectionString that work fine, my only concern is if sheet name has space character than its not return column names form corresponding sheet.
my code :

```
        if (extension == ".xls")
        {
            connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~\\ExcelUpload\\Excelsheets\\temp.xls") + ";" +
            @"Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        }
        else if (extension == ".xlsx")
        {
            connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~\\ExcelUpload\\Excelsheets\\temp.xlsx") + ";" +
            @"Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        }


        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
        DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();

        DataTable dt;
        String[] restrection = { null, null, sheetName + "$", null };
        dt = connection.GetSchema("Columns", restrection);
```

so how can we paas excelsheet name that has space character?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
var dataset = new DataSet();
var connectionString = "connstring";
var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();

var sheets = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
if (sheets == null || sheets.Rows.Count < 1) throw new InvalidOperationException("CantReadWorksheets");

foreach (DataRow sheet in sheets.Rows)
{
    var tableName = sheet["Table_Name"].ToString();
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + tableName + "]";

    var adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    adap.Fill(dataset, tableName);
}

connection.Close();
```

You can see how I'm getting the sheet names. (`try..catch` blocks were snipped)

Comment: that is fine, but my question is when you put space in your table name or sheet name its not return value

Comment: I know, but I thought maybe this approach will help because it works a bit different from yours and queries through the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String[] restrictions = { null, null, "['" + sheetName + "$']", null };
```

So if you have a worksheet TEST WORKSHEET it became 'TEST WORKSHEET$'

It's escapes me why we have to follow such WIERD naming conventions

Answer (score 0):

Should be no issue with filename containing spaces. Try to check if file exist before reading from it:

```
System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~\\ExcelUpload\\Excelsheets\\temp filename.xlsx"))
```

Comment: i had already checked file is exist or not, when i remove space from sheet name its return column name but when put space it dose not return any thing in statment connection.GetSchema("Columns", restrection);

Comment: I think he means the sheet name within Excel has spaces, not the file path.

Answer (score 0):

The code...

```
String[] restrection = { null, null, sheetName + "$", null };
```

...appends a '$' onto the sheet name. Maybe the sheet name needs to be delimited, perhaps...

```
String[] restrection = { null, null, "[" + sheetName + "]$", null };
```

...or...

```
String[] restrection = { null, null, "\"" + sheetName + "\"$", null };
```

...?

Comment: sorry but its doesn't work, i will try almost delimited but no one is work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~\\ExcelUpload\\Excelsheets\\temp.xls") + ";" +
            @"Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
```

with this:

```
string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + path +
                              ";Extended Properties=\'Excel 8.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=1;\'";
```

Same for Excel 12.0. In my case, solve the case :)