# OleDbConnection GetSchema is not returning all column headers

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

Good morning all, I'm trying to read data from an Excel spreadsheet using `OleDbConnection`, and for some reason it is stopping after column `IU`. After doing some research, it doesn't seem to make sense that there would be a maximum amount of columns read in, rather just an `OutOfMemoryException` (which is not happening).

I made a spreadsheet with 1 row and added data to each cell in that row up to KZ (quite a bit beyond the IU, but that's how far my actual spreadsheet goes).  I also made a simple console app to make sure that it's not something else in the project.  After running the console app, it still seems to not be collecting any data beyond column IU.

If anyone has any thoughts or comments, that would be great!  Thanks!

```
OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=***;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=true;IMEX=1\"");
oleDbConnection.Open();
DataTable dtColumns = oleDbConnection.GetSchema("Columns", null);
```

The real duplicate is this question: [How to read more than 256 columns from an excel file (2007 format) using OLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766466/how-to-read-more-than-256-columns-from-an-excel-file-2007-format-using-oledb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get column from Excel Sheet,if Excel sheet name contain space character i.e."Person Details"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383308/how-to-get-column-from-excel-sheet-if-excel-sheet-name-contain-space-character-i)

Comment: This one was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766466/how-to-read-more-than-256-columns-from-an-excel-file-2007-format-using-oledb

Comment: Thank you guys!  The second one answered one was the duplicate (thanks for finding that as I couldn't!).. stackoverflow.com/questions/2766466 (How can I change the question up top that says possible duplicate to link to this question?)